# JavaFX MySQL database return sum

Tags: mysql, database, javafx

I want to use datepicker to select range of dates. This range of dates is then queried in the database where the sum is counted...

My attempt:

```
public static int dateRange(){
    int value = 0;

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");
        stmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT SUM(cost) FROM Items WHERE expiration_date between '" + Budget.datePicker1.getValue() + "' and '" + Budget.datePicker2.getValue() + "'");

        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
        result.next();
        String sum = result.getString(1);
        value = Integer.parseInt(sum);

    } catch (Exception e){
        value += 0;
    }
    return value;
}
```

It works. It returns the total if the days are there so to speak. If there are no days in the database as selected in the DatePicker then 0 pops up... But it looks messed up (catch block) and I was wondering if anyone could help me with an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since the value returned by the query is an integer value, there is no need to read it as a string and parse it. Just use `result.getInt(...)`.

Second, if you are going to use a `PreparedStatement`, use it to properly set parameters, instead of building the query out of concatenated strings. Doing the latter exposes your application to [SQL injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/).

If none of your dates are in range, then the SQL query will return `NULL`. Calling `getInt()` on column in a result set that is NULL [will return `0`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt-int-), so you will get the result you want in that case anyway. If the previous value you got from a result set was SQL `NULL`, then calling `result.wasNull()` will return true, so if you really did need to handle that case separately, you could use that mechanism to do so.

You can do:

```
public static int dateRange(){
    int value = 0;

    // Use try-with-resources to make sure resources are released:
    try (
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "");
        PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT SUM(cost) FROM Items WHERE expiration_date between ? and ?");
    ) {

        stmt.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(Budget.datePicker1.getValue()));
        stmt.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(Budget.datePicker2.getValue())); 
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery();
        result.next();

        // Note that if there are no values in range, the SQL result will be NULL
        // and getInt() will return 0 anyway.
        value = result.getInt(1);

        // however, if you need to explicitly check this and do something different
        // if nothing is in range, do:
        if (result.wasNull()) {
            // nothing was in range...
        }

    } catch (SQLException e){
        // this actually indicates something went wrong. Handle it properly.
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.SEVERE, "Error accessing database", e);
        // inform user there was a db error, etc...
    } 
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've had many problems and questions with JavaFX/databases past week and seems like you're the man. Big kudos to you!